# Can "as a tool" modify more than one verb?

Tags: as, adjective-phrases

Consider this example sentence:

> The thing was owned, carried, or used as a tool.

(1) Does the "as a tool" act as an adjective for each verb?  Rewritten: "*The thing was owned (as a tool), carried (as a tool), or used as a tool.*"

(2) Or, does the "as a tool" only act on the last verb "used?"  "*...used as a tool.*"

Comment: Both parsings / permutations of parsings are syntactically possible, for what tiny difference in meaning there is. But what's the point of mentioning specifically *carrying* something as a tool as opposed to simply carrying it (with a view to *using* it as a tool, obviously). And it's a bit weird to think that some people *owned* it for, say, ceremonial purposes, while others used it as a tool. But syntactically, all possibilities are there in the text.

Comment: Actually, "all permutations" ***aren't*** possible. It would be perverse and incredibly awkward, but you could in principle parse it as *It was owned [in some unstated capacity], carried [**as a tool**], or used **as a tool***.  But note that it's *not* syntactically possible to parse the text as *It was owned [**as a tool**], carried [in some **other** capacity], or used **as a tool***. Once you start linking the adverbial element further back into the chain of preceding verbs, you can't simply discard it for any particular verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But we do understand it to potentially include all permutations, right? Maybe the OP needs to provide a second example for this question to be more focused. Would "I ate, slept, and read in the library" be a valid alternative?

Comment: @Joachim IMHO in both cases **"The thing was owned, carried, or used as a tool."** and **"I ate, slept, and read in the library"** I would interpret it to apply to all three verbs unless there was further context to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @Joachim: No, of course we don't *actually* "understand" all those bizarre possible meanings! Just because it's *syntactically* possible to parse ***as a tool*** as attaching to ***carried*** (or ***owned*** and ***carried***) besides ***used*** doesn't mean that's a *sensible* thing to do!

Comment: Yes, "as a tool" modifies all of the preceding verbs, each individually, in that specific example.  Although it's possible to come up with other examples where that would not be the case.

Comment: That sentence is *ambiguous*, so without context, it's impossible to know what it means. Grammatically, both parsings are valid, and semantically, both parsings make sense. Please [edit] your question to include the full context where that sentence came from.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You seem passionate about this matter :) That's kind of what I meant: we need to parse it in order to understand what makes sense in the first place, right? Parse, not interpret.

Comment: @J. Daniel Musick Where did you find that example? Without further context, the more salient interpretation is that "as a  tool" is complement of just "used". A careful writer (!) would spot a potential ambiguity and insert a comma after "used" if they intended  "as a tool" to be a complement of all three verbs.

Comment: @Joachim: Well, it seems to me that I only "parsed" this text because of the specific context (a question here *asking us to parse it*, not just read it "naturally"). Normally I'd just read the words and assume an interpretation of the entire text without consciously thinking of things like *Is it **owned** as a tool? What would it mean to **carry** it as a tool?* Obviously ***as a tool*** has meaning - but at the conscious level, *unless I was being asked to explicitly parse it*, it wouldn't occur to me to "back-propagate" the sense of that adverbial to modify the two ***earlier*** verbs.

Comment: Statutory Law.  I changed words to make the subject matter ambiguous.  The actual statute reads more like this:  An item, instrument or thing that is possessed, carried, or used as a weapon.